# How to solve Bad Request from Swagger UI?

Tags: user-interface, swagger, bad-request

I am using Swagger UI ( Version: 3.9.59 ).
I programed a ServiceStack contract named as GetProduct. The code is as follows.

```
[Route("/products/{Id}",
Verbs="GET",
Notes = "Gets the product by id",
Summary = "Object that doesn't need to be created directly")]
[Api("Get the product by id")]
[ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No products have been found in the repository")]
public class GetProduct
{  
   [ApiMember(AllowMultiple = false,
    DataType = "int",
    Description = "Represents the ID passed in the URI",
    IsRequired = false,
    Name = "Id",
    ParameterType = "int",
    Verb = "GET")]
    [ApiAllowableValues("family", typeof(int))] //Enum
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

After I ran Swagger UI via Google Chrome, I saw Figure 1. I entered some product id such as 1 in the textbox located in Figure 1, and then I clicked the button ‘Try it out!’.

But I got the RequestBindingException. The information in detail is as follows.

**Request URL returned is** ‘http://localhost:50712/products/{Id}?api_key=special-key’.

**Response Body returned is**

```
{
  "ResponseStatus": {
  "ErrorCode": "RequestBindingException",
  "Message": "Unable to bind request",
  "StackTrace": "   in ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.GetRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath)\r\n   in ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName)"
   }
}
```

**Response Code returned is** 400.

**Response Headers returned is**

```
Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2015 09:44:13 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: private
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcWWFuZ0xpXOWFrOWPuOi1hOaWmVxQcm9qZWN0c1xTZXJ2aWNlU3RhY2tc5a2m5Lmg6LWE5paZXOS5puexjea6kOeggVxTZXJ2aWNlU3RhY2sgU3VjY2luY3RseVzop6Pljovku7bvvIjlj6/kv67mlLnvvIlcQ2hhcHRlcjEyIC0gRG9jdW1lbnRpbmcgV2ViIFNlcnZpY2VzXFNlcnZpY2VTdGFjay5TdWNjaW5jdGx5Lkhvc3RccHJvZHVjdHNce0lkfQ==?=
Content-Length: 346
```

**The Google Chrome returned the following information.**

***Figure:***

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg7Xw.png)

How to solve the above issue?